# Android database md5 change, why change same size?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, md5

I'm developing an Android game where I use SQLite database. To verify database is correctly downloaded I use MD5. It works fine, my problem is when I make a query to the database: MD5 changes but database size remains unchanged. Does anyone know why it changes the MD5 if I don't do inserts neither updates? I only do selects.
Is there a way to check if a database is correctly with all devices?

// MD5 when install->

11-10 20:04:17.722: I/DebugCayroDev(4853): {MD5.java checkMD5} 2488C4CD2F70337BA21E4CA03EDEAFF0 and file md5: 2488c4cd2f70337ba21e4ca03edeaff0

//size its same

11-10 20:04:46.212: V/DebugCayroDev(4853): {MD5.java checkMD5} 2113748992

// MD5 Afther doing the select

11-10 20:04:46.212: I/DebugCayroDev(4853): {MD5.java checkMD5} 2488C4CD2F70337BA21E4CA03EDEAFF0 and file md5: 67d0b72e0d375ee0c5578331c4b74802

Comment: An MD5 is only valid to check that the downloaded file was correctly copied.  A database internally is like a file system and it can change at anytime.  It also pre-allocates space.  It is even possible to insert data without growing the file size.  You should not be using the same MD% after any database access.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How can I know if an internal Android database is the same as another external db?

Comment: I don't get your scenario.  You know it was downloaded OK, what are you trying to compare it with and why?

Comment: I want to know if a device database is equal to an external database. If they are not equals I want to show a popup saying to user need update database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you can't rely on a hash of the database file to tell you whether it's been updated.

The only suggestion that I can think of is to add a table to your database that holds a timestamp of the last update to the database. Whatever updates the database on the server side would have to update that timestamp whenever it updates the database in any way.

Then, you can compare the local and server timestamps to see if the versions match